# Displaying data in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, json

I have a value stored in array variable `item` like

```
var item = JSON.stringify(product);
cartproduct[cartproduct.length] = item;
```

`item` holds data such as

```
{
  "Product": "1001",
  "Brand": "Dell",
  "Model": "Inspiron ",
  "Price":"25000"
}
```

Now i want to display this `item` data in respective jqgrid columns like Product, Brand, Model ..

I saw one jsFiddle example like 
    http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/yNw3C/

Now all I want is my `item` value in the format of `data`.

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"]];

var item = [[1000,"Sony","Vaio",40000]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var itemFormatted = [[
  item.Product,
  item.Brand,
  item.Model,
  item.Price
]];

// Now itemFormatted will be in the correct format
```

Check out [Working with Javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more information.

Comment: @user2440125 Any luck with this answer?